# Element wise addition of multiple nested lists python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have nested lists that I want to add element wise. They will be the same length but the user can input the length of each list and the amount they want (so it will vary). How can I change this [[1,4,5],[4,7,2],[3,5,6]] to [8,16,13]. It doesn't have to be 3 elements and there could be more than 3 lists. Can someone help me pleaee. This is in Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to "repack" the lists (so that the first elements are one chunk, the second ones also on chunk etc). For this to work you need to unpack the lists first using `*`. Then sum over the chunks that you created using `zip`.

```
a = [[1,4,5],[4,7,2],[3,5,6]] 
[sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
```